# wordpress search modification with bbpress

Tags: wordpress, search, bbpress

I need to make a modification in bbpress search and I want to ask is it possible to do that ?

If the post type is reply, do the search only in post content, not in the post title (like in default search)?

Maybe is it possible to do with a hook ?